# How to extract all the columns from a data frame based on a column in another data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, extract

I have two data frames. I want to extract all the columns from a data frame based on another data frame column.

```
df1:

sample
 GY
 AP
 A9
 MB
 AU

df2:

 num  start end length  GY A9 MB AP JK GH AU
  2    23    24   567   5   6  7  8  9  0  1
  2    3     44   57    8   6  7  3  4  0  9
  2    234   54   67    5   6  7  8  9  0  1

result:
   num  start end length  GY A9 MB AP  AU
    2    23    24   567   5   6  7  8  1
    2    3     44   57    8   6  7  3  9
    2    234   54   67    5   6  7  8  1
```

I tried in this way but it didn't work out:

```
 u <- df1[df1$sample %in% colnames(df2),]
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With:

```
df2[, c(1:4, which(colnames(df2) %in% df1$sample))]
```

you get:

```
  num start end length GY A9 MB AP AU
1   2    23  24    567  5  6  7  8  1
2   2     3  44     57  8  6  7  3  9
3   2   234  54     67  5  6  7  8  1
```

And this also works:

```
df2[, c(rep(TRUE,4), tail(colnames(df2) %in% df1$sample, -4))]
```